# Any way to send notifications to different Emails on success/failure of SqlServerAgent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maintenance

SQL Server 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2008R2

Is there any way to send notifications to different Emails:

- on success of an Sql Server Agent job to one Email address and on failure - to another ?
- on success (or failure) of a particular job step (but not the whole job)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use tsql to do that.

in the job step after your main job step add 2 more job steps:

[image]

step 2--success email

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'YOUR MAIL PROFILE',
    @recipients = 'COMPANYMAIL@COMPANY.COM',
    @body = 'Copy and Purge BAKs success !!',
    @subject = 'Copy and Purge BAKs success',
-- to send file attachments 
    @file_attachments = 'D:\logs\log.TXT',
  -- Change below if you want to include query results from a table in the email. 
  -- Note that below is not in HTML
    @query = 'select column1, column2 from table1';
```

step 3-- failure email

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'YOUR MAIL PROFILE',
    @recipients = 'COMPANYMAIL@COMPANY.COM',
    @body = 'Copy and Purge BAKs failed !!',
    @subject = 'Copy and Purge BAKs failed',
-- to send file attachments 
    @file_attachments = 'D:\logs\log.TXT',
  -- Change below if you want to include query results from a table in the email. 
  -- Note that below is not in HTML
    @query = 'select column1, column2 from table1';
```

and then use tsql `sp_send_dbmail`

Note: If you want HTML email to be send out, I have a script for that to help you out.